# Database - Rating, Commenting, Etc. on Multiple Entities (Blog, Status, Photo, Etc.)

Tags: social-networking, database-schema

We're going to leave users and other social media mechanisms (such as notifications, friends, etc.) out of this question. We want to focus on what a user may post and how other users interact with them.

So far, we would have tables for each entity.

I figure that we will have tables for each Entity-Interaction combination to keep track of who rated, commented, etc. on which record. For example, for Blog, we would have BlogRatings, BlogComments, BlogFlags, BlogLikes, and BlogShares.

But for each entity {E} we add on later, we will need to create the tables for {E}Ratings, {E}Comments, {E}Flags, {E}Likes, and {E}Shares. Then if we come up with a new interaction, we need to write as many new tables as there already exists entities so that users may perform the new interaction on everything. This seems really tedious.

How would I scheme such tables to minimize/ease maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Single Table Inheritance, though you might want to look into Class Table Inheritance in this case.

```
--postgres syntax

create table nodes (
  node_id serial primary key,
  type varchar(20) not null check (type in ('BLOG_POST','PHOTO','STATUS_UPDATE') ),
  blog_title text null,
  blog_body text null,
  status_body text null,
  ...
);

create table comments (
  comment_id serial primary key,
  node_id int not null references nodes(node_id),
  comment text not null,
  parent_comment_id int null references comments(id)
  ...
);
```

You could also consider a comment to be a type of node. You could group likes, ratings, flags, and maybe shares into a "feedback" type as well